# Remove items in string paragraph if they belong to a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list, replace, beautifulsoup

```
 import urllib2,sys
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString

 obama_4427_url = 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427'
 obama_4427_html = urllib2.urlopen(obama_4427_url).read()

 obama_4427_soup = BeautifulSoup(obama_4427_html)

 # find the speech itself within the HTML

 obama_4427_div = obama_4427_soup.find('div',{'id': 'transcript'},{'class': 'displaytext'})

 # convert soup to string for easier processing

 obama_4427_str = str(obama_4427_div)

 # list of characters to be removed from obama_4427_str

 remove_char = ['<br/>','</p>','</div>','<div class="indent" id="transcript">','<h2>','</h2>','<p>']
 remove_char


 for char in obama_4427_str:
 if char in obama_4427_str:
     obama_4427_replace = obama_4427_str.replace(remove_char,'')


 obama_4427_replace = obama_4427_str.replace(remove_char,'')

 print(obama_4427_replace)
```

Using `BeautifulSoup`, I scraped one of Obama's speeches off of the above website. Now, I need to replace some residual HTML in an efficient manner. I've stored a list of elements I'd like to eliminate in `remove_char`. I'm trying to write a simple `for` statement, but am getting the error: `TypeError: expected a character object buffer`. It's a beginner question, I know, but how can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `BeautifulSoup` already , you can directly use `obama_4427_div.text` instead of `str(obama_4427_div)` to get the correctly formatted text. Then the text you get would not contain any residual `html` elements, etc.

Example -

```
>>> obama_4427_div = obama_4427_soup.find('div',{'id': 'transcript'},{'class': 'displaytext'})
>>> obama_4427_str = obama_4427_div.text
>>> print(obama_4427_str)

Transcript
To Chairman Dean and my great friend Dick Durbin; and to all my fellow citizens of this great nation;

With profound gratitude and great humility, I accept your nomination for the presidency of the United States.

Let me express my thanks to the historic slate of candidates who accompanied me on this ...
...
...
...
Thank you, God Bless you, and God Bless the United States of America.
```

---

For completeness, for removing elements from a string, I would create a list of elements to remove (like the `remove_char` list you have created) and then we can do `str.replace()` on the string for each element in the list. Example -

```
obama_4427_str = str(obama_4427_div)
remove_char = ['<br/>','</p>','</div>','<div class="indent" id="transcript">','<h2>','</h2>','<p>']
for char in remove_char:
    obama_4427_str = obama_4427_str.replace(char,'')
```

Comment: That's outstanding - thank you. For completeness, though, how would I go about removing elements like `<br/>` or `</p>` in a `for` loop?

Comment: Interesting that 2 different users are trying to parse the same Obama speech at the same time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593031/httperror-not-found-in-urllib2-and-beautifulsoup

Comment: @CarterMasterson Updated with an example on how to do do replacing in the stirng.

Comment: wow, this is why it is called BeautifulSoup. I don't see how it could be any fewer characters to type ;-) Very nice. Thanks for sharing.